# callback_url_duplicated function error in Database with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a form for insert pages on the database,the trouble is that I can't detected in form if a URL is duplicated in my database,because I should to configure a callback function.The error is only on the callback function because I can insert,delete and create pages with this form.

This is my Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Create_Pages extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        /*$this->load->library('pagination');*/
        $this->load->model('Create_Pages_Model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('view_error');
        }
    }
    public function add_new_page()
    {   
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
           {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];
            $this->load->view('view_admin_content_panel', $data);
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->model('Create_Pages_Model');
            $data_pages = array(
            'TitlePage' => $this->input->post('TitlePage'),
            'SectionPage' => $this->input->post('SectionPage'),
            'CategoryPage' => $this->input->post('CategoryPage'),
            'NamePage' => $this->input->post('NamePage'),
            'DescriptionPage' => $this->input->post('DescriptionPage'),
            'BodyPage' => $this->input->post('BodyPage')
            );
                if($this->input->post())
                {
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('TitlePage','Title of the Page','required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('SectionPage','Section of the Page','required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('CategoryPage','Category of the Page','required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('NamePage','Name of the Page','required|min_length[5]|callback_check_namepage[$str]|xss_clean|url_title');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DescriptionPage','Description of the Page','required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('BodyPage','Content of the Page','required|min_length[5]');

                    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
                    {

                        $page_inserted = $this->Create_Pages_Model->addPage();
                        redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        $this->load->view('admin/user/add_new_page_view');
                    }
                    function check_namepage($str)
                    {

                       $PageName =  $this->db->where('NamePage', $NamePage);
                       $query = $this->db->select('pages', array('NamePage' =>  $NamePage));
                       if($query  == $PageName){
                            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_namepage', '%Should be Unique Name Page because we can\'t duplicate the URL of the page');   
                            return FALSE;
                        }
                        elseif($NamePage  != $query)
                        {
                            return TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->load->view('admin/user/add_new_page_view');
                }
           }
           else
           {
             $this->load->view('view_error');
           }

    }       

}
```

This is my model code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Create_Pages_Model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('view_error');
    }
    public function addPage(){
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
            {
                $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];
                $this->load->database();
                $add_page = $this->input->post();
                unset($add_page['insert']);
                $this->db->insert('pages',$add_page);
                return $this->db->insert_id();
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('view_error');
            }
    }
}
```

And this this is my my view page,for insert the pages into the database:

```
<body>  
<div id="main">
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Create a New Page</h1>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

   <p>Please enter your details below to form.</p>
<?php 
$title_page = array(
              'name'        => 'TitlePage',
              'id'          => 'TitlePage',
              'maxlength'   => '490',
              'size'        => '90',
              'type'         => 'text',
              'style'       => 'position:relative;min-height:40px;width:100%;',
              'value'       => set_value('TitlePage'),
            );
$section_page = array(
              'name'        => 'SectionPage',
              'id'          => 'SectionPage',
              'maxlength'   => '390',
              'type'         => 'text',
              'size'        => '90',
              'style'       => 'position:relative;min-height:40px;width:100%;',
              'value'       => set_value('SectionPage'),
            );
 $category_page = array(
              'name'        => 'CategoryPage',
              'id'          => 'CategoryPage',
              'maxlength'   => '290',
              'type'         => 'text',
              'size'        => '90',
              'style'       => 'position:relative;min-height:40px;width:100%;',
              'value'       => set_value('CategoryPage'),
            );
$name_page = array(
              'name'        => 'NamePage',
              'id'          => 'NamePage',
              'maxlength'   => '290',
              'type'         => 'text',
              'size'        => '90',
              'style'       => 'position:relative;min-height:40px;width:100%;',
              'value'       => set_value('NamePage'),
            );
$description_page = array(
              'name'        => 'DescriptionPage',
              'id'          => 'DescriptionPage',
              'maxlength'   => '290',
              'type'         => 'text',
              'size'        => '90',
              'style'       => 'position:relative;min-height:40px;width:100%;',
              'value'       => set_value('DescriptionPage'),
            );
$body_page = array(
              'name'        => 'BodyPage',
              'id'          => 'BodyPage',
              'maxlength'   => '290',
              'type'         => 'text',
              'size'        => '90',
              'style'       => 'position:relative;min-height:320px;width:100%;',
              'value'       => set_value('BodyPage'),
              'rows'        => '15',
              'cols'        => '80',

            );
?><?php echo form_open();?>
<?php echo form_label('Title of the Page:','lbl_titlepage');?><br/>
<?php echo form_input($title_page);?><?php echo form_error('TitlePage'); ?><br/>
<?php echo form_label('Section of the Page:','lbl_sectionpage');?><br/>
<?php echo form_input($section_page);?><?php echo form_error('SectionPage'); ?><br/>
<?php echo form_label('Category of the Page:','lbl_categorypage');?><br/>
<?php echo form_input($category_page);?><?php echo form_error('CategoryPage'); ?><br/>
<?php echo form_label('Name of the Page (URL):','lbl_namepage');?><br/>
<?php echo form_input($name_page);?><?php echo form_error('NamePage'); ?><br/>
<?php echo form_label('Description of the Page:','lbl_descriptionpage');?><br/>
<?php echo form_input($description_page);?><?php echo form_error('DescriptionPage'); ?><br/>
<?php echo form_label('Contentent of the Page:','lbl_BodyPage');?><br/>
<?php echo form_textarea($body_page);?><?php echo form_error('BodyPage'); ?><br/><br/>
<?php echo form_submit('insert','Create Page')?><br/>
<?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `ID_Page` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TitlePage` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `SectionPage` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `CategoryPage` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `NamePage` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `BodyPage` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `DescriptionPage` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;


ALTER TABLE `pages`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Page`);

ALTER TABLE `pages`
  MODIFY `ID_Page` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `check_namepage()` method outside of `add_new_page()` method.
and you do not need to pass `$str` in `callback_check_namepage[$str]`. It should be just `callback_check_namepage` because CI will automatically pass the **user provided field data** to the callback function. So, in the callback `check_namepage($str)`, `$str` will be available automatically.

**So, your Controller will be like this:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Create_Pages extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    /*$this->load->library('pagination');*/
    $this->load->model('Create_Pages_Model');
}
public function index()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('view_error');
    }
}
public function add_new_page()
{   
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
       {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];
        $this->load->view('view_admin_content_panel', $data);
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('Create_Pages_Model');
        $data_pages = array(
        'TitlePage' => $this->input->post('TitlePage'),
        'SectionPage' => $this->input->post('SectionPage'),
        'CategoryPage' => $this->input->post('CategoryPage'),
        'NamePage' => $this->input->post('NamePage'),
        'DescriptionPage' => $this->input->post('DescriptionPage'),
        'BodyPage' => $this->input->post('BodyPage')
        );
            if($this->input->post())
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('TitlePage','Title of the Page','required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('SectionPage','Section of the Page','required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('CategoryPage','Category of the Page','required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('NamePage','Name of the Page','required|min_length[5]|callback_check_namepage|xss_clean|url_title'); // [$str] is removed
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('DescriptionPage','Description of the Page','required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('BodyPage','Content of the Page','required|min_length[5]');

                if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
                {
                    // moved below
                    $page_inserted = $this->Create_Pages_Model->addPage();
                        redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
                }
                else
                {   
                        $this->load->view('admin/user/add_new_page_view');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('admin/user/add_new_page_view');
            }
       }
       else
       {
         $this->load->view('view_error');
       }

    }       
    private function check_namepage($str)
    {
        // you have error here, solve it           
        $PageName =  $this->db->where('NamePage', $NamePage);
        $query = $this->db->select('pages', array('NamePage' =>  $NamePage));
        if($query  == $PageName){
           $this->form_validation->set_message('check_namepage', '%Should be Unique Name Page because we can\'t duplicate the URL of the page');   
            return FALSE;
        }
        elseif($NamePage  != $query)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }


}
```